# How to split each input by a new line in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, spacing

I'm trying get 5 string inputs from the user and those inputs are going to be stored in an array. When I enter something like "Hello World" and hit a new line I can only enter 3 more words. So I want each user input to be a sentence and hitting enter should ask the user for another input on a new line.

Here is my code so far:

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);   
String ask1 = user_input.next()+"\n";
String ask2 = user_input.next()+"\n";
String ask3 = user_input.next()+"\n";
String ask4 = user_input.next()+"\n";
String ask5 = user_input.next();
String[] cars = {ask1, ask2, ask3, ask4, ask5};
```

Comment: Unclear to me, please rephrase

Comment: Did you try with `user_input.nextLine()`?

Comment: When the program runs in the console and i write a sentence in the console on the same line each word of the sentence is stored as a separate element in the array rather I want to store the whole sentence as a single element

Comment: i tried user_input.nextLine() it worked thank you

Comment: Then `nextLine` should definitely do what you want. If it's not, you're dong it wrong

Comment: nextLine worked thanks guys it didnt work at first i think because i didnt add it to all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()), `Scanner.next()`:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

As the default delimiter used by `Scanner` is whitespace, calling `next()` will get you individual words from user input. When you want to capture multiple words that end with a newline, you should use [`Scanner.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) instead.

Additionally, you can remove code duplication (which you always should do, keeping things [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) by creating the array beforehand and allocating the user input entries within a loop:

```
final int numberOfCars = 5;
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);   
String[] cars = new String[numberOfCars];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCars; i++) {
    cars[i] = userInput.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped. If you found this answer useful, you can consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I was trying to but I cant seem to figure it out if u tell me i ll gladly mark it as the solution

Comment: So what are you having problems with exactly?

Comment: Your code is what i needed my trouble is marking ur answer as the solution lol

Comment: got it its the check mark next to your post haha thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you have a certain keyword or phrase that the user can type which stops the program. Here, I made a simple program that uses the java.util.Scanner object to receive keyboard input. Each value is stored in a java.util.ArrayList called "inputs." When the user is done entering input, he/she will type "stop" and the program will stop.

```
import java.util.*; //you need this for ArrayList and Scanner

public class Input{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in); //create a scanner object
        ArrayList<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>(); //I used a java.util.ArrayList simply because it is more flexible than an array
        String temp = ""; //create a temporary string which will represent  the current input string

                while(!((temp = user_input.next()).equals("stop"))){ //set temp equal to the  new input each iteration
                inputs.add(temp); //add the temp string to the arraylist
                }
    }
}
```

If you want to convert the ArrayList to a normal String[], use this code:

```
String[] inputArray = new String[inputs.size];
for(int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++){
    inputArray[i] = inputs.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Although not wrong, that doesn't really answer the original question.

Comment: Here is how I understood his question and rephrased it: "When I enter a string, such as "hello world" and press enter, the program only allows me to enter three more strings of input, then it stops. I want each string to be stored in an array (I assume he means a regular built-in java array). I want a user to enter input and have a new line created for further input."
His program has an individual variable for each new line. If he only has 5 variables, he can only get 5 inputs. My solution allows for as many inputs as a user wants before typing "stop".

Answer (score 0):

You can make this more generic by storing your question on an array and looping through a for loop prompting for input until you have question. This why when you have more questions you can add them to list without changing anything else on the code.

Then, to answer your original question regarding creating a String array, you could use following method `String[] a = answers.toArray(new String[answers.size()]);`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>(5){{
        add("What is your name?");
        add("What is school you went to?");
        add("Do you like dogs?");
        add("What is pats name?");
        add("Are you batman?");
    }};

    ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>(questions.size()); // initialize answers with the same size as question array
    String input = ""; // Stores user input here
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(String question : questions){
      System.out.println(question); // Here we adding a new line and the user type his answer on a new line
      input = scanner.nextLine();
      answers.add(input); // Store the answer on answers array
    }
    System.out.println("Thank you.");
    String[] a = answers.toArray(new String[answers.size()]); // THis converts ArrayList to String[]
    System.out.println("You entered: " + a.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this instead:

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);   
String ask1 = user_input.nextLine()+"\n";
String ask2 = user_input.nextLine()+"\n";
String ask3 = user_input.nextLine()+"\n";
String ask4 = user_input.nextLine()+"\n";
String ask5 = user_input.nextLine();
String[] cars = {ask1, ask2, ask3, ask4, ask5};
```